# Select everything except the content of a single div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following DOM structure:

- body

  - several elements (divs, etc)
  - `div.Popup` including several child-nodes (possibly deep down)
  - several elements (divs, etc)

Now I would like to find a CSS selector to set `cursor: default` for everything except `div.Popup` and it's child-nodes.

Is there any way to do this?

The `:not` selector does not seem to work for this scenario.

**Example**

```
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here.
    <input type="text"/> 
    <a href="#">Link</a> 
    <span class="Action">Action</span>
</div>
<div class="Popup">Cursor should be unchanged here.
    <input type="text"/> 
    <a href="#">Link</a> 
    <span class="Action">Action</span>
</div>
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here.
    <input type="text"/> 
    <a href="#">Link</a> 
    <span class="Action">Action</span>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bpp7dnst/4/)

Comment: Could you set cursor:default for _all_ elements instead and override the setting for div.popup subtrees by a subsequent css rule ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using: * {cursor: default} and then override that for div.Popup?

Comment: @ChrisSpittles: There are other cursor-definitions on the page. If I use "!important", I would overwrite these inside div.Popup. Without "!important", this will not work for all elements.

Comment: @collapsar: I would love to do that, but I would need a rule that "disables" the other rule instead of setting an actual value for "cursor".

Comment: @Harry: Not really. The cursor on the div in the middle should remain unchanged: "default" on the text, "text" on the input-field and "pointer" on the link.

Comment: @Andreas: How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bpp7dnst/6/). Note: I am assuming the `Popup` class is to an element at the first level below the `body`.

Comment: @Harry: That's a good one! I just checked the dom-tree in my application and it will work perfectly fine for mem since all ".Popup" have a well-defined path down from the body-tag :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the code given in question (assuming the element with `class='Popup'` is a direct child of the `body`), the below selector would satisfy the requirement.

```
body >:not(.Popup),
body >:not(.Popup) * {
    cursor: default;
    /* Insert any other required styles */
}
```

```css
.Action {
  cursor: pointer;
}
body >:not(.Popup),
body >:not(.Popup) * {
  cursor: default;
  color: green; /* just for better visual depiction of selected elements */
}
```

```html
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here.
  <input type="text" /> 
  <a href="#">Link</a>  
  <span class="Action">Action</span>
</div>
<div class="Popup">Cursor should be unchanged here.
  <input type="text" /> 
  <a href="#">Link</a>  
  <span class="Action">Action</span>
</div>
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here.
  <input type="text" /> 
  <a href="#">Link</a>  
  <span class="Action">Action</span>
</div>
```

This method would work (even if the element with `class='Popup'` is not a direct child of the `body`) as long as the element with `class='Popup'` has a single defined selector path. Below is a sample snippet for such a scenario.

```css
.Action {
  cursor: pointer;
}
body >:not(.container),
body > .container >:not(.Popup),
body > .container >:not(.Popup) * {
  cursor: default;
  color: green;
  /* just for better visual depiction of selected elements */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Cursor should be 'default' here.
    <input type="text" />
    <a href="#">Link</a> 
    <span class="Action">Action</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Popup">Cursor should be unchanged here.
    <input type="text" />
    <a href="#">Link</a> 
    <span class="Action">Action</span>
  </div>
  <div>Cursor should be 'default' here.
    <input type="text" />
    <a href="#">Link</a> 
    <span class="Action">Action</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>abcd</div>
```

---

The key part of the selector (and probably the reason why earlier attempts had not worked) is the usage of children selector (`>`) as opposed to normal descendant or everything selectors (`*`).

If the selector was written like `body :not(.Popup)` or `body *:not(.Popup)`, we would be selecting **all** elements which do not have `class='Popup'` and hence even the `input`, `a` and `span` elements would get selected. This is because they also do not have `class='Popup'` (and are present within `body`). You can see how the text color changes for all of them in the below code snippet to visualize better.

```css
.Action {
  cursor: pointer;
}
body :not(.Popup) {
  cursor: default;
  color: green; /* just for better visual depiction of selected elements */
}
```

```html
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here.
  <input type="text" value="dummy"/> 
  <a href="#">Link</a>  
  <span class="Action">Action</span>
</div>
<div class="Popup">Cursor should be unchanged here.
  <input type="text" value="dummy"/> 
  <a href="#">Link</a>  
  <span class="Action">Action</span>
</div>
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here.
  <input type="text" value="dummy"/> 
  <a href="#">Link</a>  
  <span class="Action">Action</span>
</div>
```

```
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here. <!-- Selected -->
  <input type="text" value="dummy"/>  <!-- Selected -->
  <a href="#">Link</a>                <!-- Selected -->
  <span class="Action">Action</span>  <!-- Selected -->
</div>
<div class="Popup">Cursor should be unchanged here. <!-- Not Selected -->
  <input type="text" value="dummy"/>  <!-- Selected -->
  <a href="#">Link</a>                <!-- Selected -->
  <span class="Action">Action</span>  <!-- Selected -->
</div>
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here. <!-- Selected -->
  <input type="text" value="dummy"/>  <!-- Selected -->
  <a href="#">Link</a>                <!-- Selected -->
  <span class="Action">Action</span>  <!-- Selected -->
</div>
```

> Note: I am not sure what is wrong with just `:not(.Popup)` and `*:not(.Popup)` but they don't seem to work at all (atleast in Chrome v24). It seems like a selector of the form `element:not(x)` or `element :not(x)` or `element > :not(x)` is required.

By using the children selector, we are specifically selecting only elements (and its descendants) which don't have `class='Popup'` and are also children (not descendants) of the `body` tag. Hence, the elements whose parent is not `body` are not selected.

```
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here. <!-- Selected by 1st selector-->
  <input type="text" value="dummy"/>  <!-- Selected by descendant selector-->
  <a href="#">Link</a>                <!-- Selected by descendant selector-->
  <span class="Action">Action</span>  <!-- Selected by descendant selector-->
</div>
<div class="Popup">Cursor should be unchanged here. <!-- Not Selected -->
  <input type="text" value="dummy"/>  <!-- Not Selected -->
  <a href="#">Link</a>                <!-- Not Selected -->
  <span class="Action">Action</span>  <!-- Not Selected -->
</div>
<div>Cursor should be 'default' here. <!-- Selected by 1st selector -->
  <input type="text" value="dummy"/>  <!-- Selected by descendant selector-->
  <a href="#">Link</a>                <!-- Selected by descendant selector-->
  <span class="Action">Action</span>  <!-- Selected by descendant selector-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
* {
   cursor: default
}
div.Popup, div.Popup * {
   cursor: auto
}
```

Comment: This does not work in case there are other styles changing the cursor. Overwriting these with "!important" will not help either IMO. I adjusted the jsFiddle above to incluse this case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So what you would need to do is set the cursor to be `cursor:default;` for the body, and then re-assign `cursor:pointer;` or whatever pointer you want.

```
body {
    cursor:default;
}

popUp:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

If you want the cursor to be the default one else where, then the code can be simplified to be:

```
popUp:hover {cursor:pointer;}
```